# Referring to a user by several possible identities

Tags: api-design

My application keeps multiple profile attributes for its users, such as:

- An internal userId
- Their phone number
- Their email

etc. Each attribute is unique to a user; they can all be used as identity information.

I am designing an API with operations that refer to a specific user, eg *charge*. 
I want to allow clients to identify users by any of the available profile attributes. In my specific domain, it is not possible to just enforce clients to use the internal userId, even if they can receive it in a separate call (eg *getUserIdFromProfileAttribute*).

Assuming the *charge* operation, it is a POST request with a JSON document inside the body. What would be the best way to identify the users? I am thinking one of the following:

1. Top-level key/value pairs for both the id and the id type:

   ```
   {
       "userId": <id>,
       "userIdType": <idType>
   }
   ```
2. Nested key/value pairs inside a user key:

   ```
   {
       "user": {
           "id": <id>,
           "type": <idType>
       }
   }
   ```
3. Single key/value pair, using a URI format with (possibly) custom protocols:

   ```
   {
        "user": <uri>      # eg id:1234, tel:+19283912000, email:user@mail.com
   }
   ```
4. Single key/value pair, using different keys for each id (one key per call):

   ```
   {
       "userId": <id>                                 *OR*
       "userMsisdn": <msisdn>                         *OR*
       "userEmail": <email>
   }
   ```
5. Same as above, but nested inside a user key:

   ```
   {
       "user": {
           "id": <id>                                 *OR*
           "msisdn": <msisdn>
       }
   }
   ```

Any suggestions about best practices? Anyone can point me to some standard / widely used APIs with a similar need?

I should repeat that using just the internal userId in all calls is not possible, and using a separate call for each id (eg *chargeById*, *chargeByEmail*) is not practical as there are many such calls.